# android-how to make a layout on top of every thing and not transpranet

Tags: android, slidingdrawer, slidingmenu, android-sliding

I am working on a bottom toolbar for android by forking the `SlidingUpPanel` at:

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

I want to make it always on top of every thing not defined in my sliding up panel. But when I slide it up, if there is something behind it, my layout is acting like it's transparent. How can I fix it to act like a real toolbar ?

before sliding :
[image]

after sliding :
[image]

source : http://www.4shared.com/rar/jeA2gbZy/androidslidinguppanel-master.html

Comment: can we see your code/layout?

Comment: yes with pleasure , I edit the question as you can see in source section.

Comment: It looks like you need to change the background alpha, do you have the xml or code for defining the view?

Comment: yes it i rar file a put in source section, but if I change the alpha, a button that is under the sliding view won't be click able ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a background to the button and change text color.
I dont think they are transparent but the text just has the same color and the button has a transparent background by default.

Comment: as you can see in pictures above the "Large Text" is belong to root layout but when the sliding layout goes up "Large Text" placed on it.

Comment: in addition the rectangular button is not belong to sliding layout but it's on top of it and also click able

Answer (score 1):

Add a onClickListener to the root view of sliding up pannel.I did that and it works well, hope it works for you too.